# Вывод звука в C

Tags: c

Какие существуют способы вывода звука в C. Желательно, что бы это были стандартные библиотеки/способы, т.к. это для низкоуровневого программирования.

Comment: Тк в С я ещё не много понимаю, то извиняюсь за нечеткость поставления вопроса и условия.

Comment: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/105923-c-program-play-sound.html

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: Все, т.к. программа будет работать на Linux и на Windows

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке С вообще нет средств работы со звуком. Если нужно низкоуровнево - то код будет кардинально различаться для разных операционных систем, т.к. API Windows и Linux кардинально различаются. Низкий уровень и кроссплатформенность во многом противоречат друг другу. Проще взять готовое (высокоуровневое) решение, типа OpenAL, и им пользоваться.

Comment: Для вывода звука Вы можете воспользоватся кросплатформеными библиотеками [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) или [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: Раз надо - значит надо, но мне нужно знать как это реализовать...